# How to add Bearer Authorization to AdonisJS?

Tags: authorization, bearer-token, adonis.js

I'm using AdonisJS to develop my backend API. As the project is growing big and belongs to a private company, I need to add a Bearer Token Authorization whenever calling an API endpoint. Just like this:

```
headers: { 
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` 
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in AdonisJS 5?

Answer (score 0):

add auth middleware on route

example :

```
Route.get('posts', 'PostsController.index').middleware(["auth:jwt"])
```